# Python 3.11 http.server problem with the path

Tags: python-3.x, web, path

I created this program, but whenever I start the server, there are just weird files (probably Windows files) and when I run it there is also nothing in the log. I tried to add one Backslash each. I tried many methods, but nothing wants to work. I need help for my path directory to the html,css and JavaScript files.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
import http.server
import socketserver
import threading
import webbrowser

class ServerApp:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = tk.Tk()
        self.window.title("Private Server")
        self.window.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.on_closing)

        self.port = 9000
        self.path = r'C:\Users\Owner\Desktop'

        self.port_label = tk.Label(self.window, text="Port:", font=("TkDefaultFont", 14))
        self.port_entry = tk.Entry(self.window, font=("TkDefaultFont", 14))
        self.port_entry.insert(0, str(self.port))

        self.path_label = tk.Label(self.window, text="Path:", font=("TkDefaultFont", 14))
        self.path_entry = tk.Entry(self.window, font=("TkDefaultFont", 14))
        self.path_entry.insert(0, self.path)

        self.start_button = tk.Button(self.window, text="Start Server", command=self.start_server, font=("TkDefaultFont", 14))
        self.stop_button = tk.Button(self.window, text="Stop Server", command=self.stop_server, state=tk.DISABLED, font=("TkDefaultFont", 14))

        self.url_label = tk.Label(self.window, text="", font=("TkDefaultFont", 14))
        self.users_label = tk.Label(self.window, text="", font=("TkDefaultFont", 14))

        self.port_label.pack()
        self.port_entry.pack()
        self.path_label.pack()
        self.path_entry.pack()
        self.start_button.pack()
        self.stop_button.pack()
        self.url_label.pack()
        self.users_label.pack()

    def start_server(self):
        try:
            port = int(self.port_entry.get())
            path = self.path_entry.get()

            handler = http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
            handler.extensions_map.update({
                '.js': 'application/javascript',
            })
            handler.directory = path

            socketserver.TCPServer.allow_reuse_address = True
            self.httpd = socketserver.TCPServer(("", port), handler)

            url = f"http://localhost:{port}"
            webbrowser.open(url)
            threading.Thread(target=self.httpd.serve_forever).start()

            self.url_label.config(text=f"URL: {url}")
            # TODO: Add code to show users on the page

            self.start_button.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
            self.stop_button.config(state=tk.NORMAL)
        except Exception as e:
            messagebox.showerror("Error", str(e))

    def stop_server(self):
        try:
            if hasattr(self, 'httpd'):
                self.httpd.shutdown()
                delattr(self, 'httpd')

                url = ""
                users = ""

                self.url_label.config(text=f"URL: {url}")
                # TODO: Add code to show users on the page

                self.start_button.config(state=tk.NORMAL)
                self.stop_button.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
        except Exception as e:
            messagebox.showerror("Error", str(e))

    def on_closing(self):
        if hasattr(self, 'httpd'):
            if messagebox.askokcancel("Quit", "Do you want to stop the server and quit?"):
                try:
                    if hasattr(self, 'httpd'):
                        self.httpd.shutdown()
                        delattr(self, 'httpd')
                except Exception as e:
                    messagebox.showerror("Error", str(e))
                finally:
                    self.window.destroy()
        else:
            if messagebox.askokcancel("Quit", "Do you want to quit?"):
                try:
                    if hasattr(self, 'httpd'):
                        self.httpd.shutdown()
                        delattr(self, 'httpd')
                except Exception as e:
                    messagebox.showerror("Error", str(e))
                finally:
                    self.window.destroy()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = ServerApp()
    app.window.mainloop()
```

I'm not a Python expert, im not sure what to do now.

When I run the programme with python, then it doesn't work, but when I run it in VS code I can just go to Desktop. If I try to go somewhere in a folder in Desktop, then it just shows me files from Desktop. It's weird.